# Sort list by frequency and by value in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of numbers say, [2,2,3,3,4,1] I want to sort by frequency and if the frequency count (ascending) is same then sort by value (also ascending). Soln would be [1,4,2,2,3,3]

For frequency

```
from collections import Counter
print sorted(arr, key=Counter(arr).get)
```

But I am not sure how to sort by value for same frequency count elements

Comment: Look in a Python sort tutorial for how to use a secondary key.
One common way across languages is to sort *first* by your secondary key, *then* by your primary key, using a stable sort (which most languages provide).

Comment: `sorted(l, key=lambda x: [l.count(x),x])`

Comment: @bro-grammer This will be pretty slow for big lists, because it'll have to go through the list for every item

Comment: @Omer yes I agree. Probably a better way would be to build a frequency dict using `Counter`. I was just trying to show OP how to use multiple keys to sort.

Comment: I like @Prune's idea. First sort by value then by frequency.

     from collections import Counter
    def custom_sort(l):
       l = sorted(l)
       return  sorted(l, key=Counter(l).get)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow up on @bro-grammer's comment (I used a tuple for the keys and called Counter only once):

There's this method which first has to go through the list for counting and then some more for sorting.

```
from collections import Counter
def perseus_sort(l):
    counter = Counter(l)
    return sorted(l, key=lambda x: (counter[x], x))
```

There's probably some clever algorithm that can somehow combine both of these but my intuition that it would be pretty complicated and more than you need

Answer (score 2):

This is one way via `numpy.unique` and `numpy.lexsort`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([2,2,3,3,4,1])

c = dict(zip(*np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)))

res = arr[np.lexsort((arr, list(map(c.get, arr))))]

# array([1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

Some benchmarking below for a large array:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 9, 100000)

def jp(arr):
    c = dict(zip(*np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)))
    res = arr[np.lexsort((arr, list(map(c.get, arr))))]
    return res

def perseus_sort(l):
    counter = Counter(l)
    return sorted(l, key=lambda x: (counter[x], x))

%timeit jp(arr)            # 39.2 ms
%timeit perseus_sort(arr)  # 118 ms
```